# Anyone can recommended book about three dimensional geometry?

Tags: geometry, book-recommendation

I want to learn about differential geometry,but I have read It required some background from  three dimensional geometry.But I have a few backgroud abount it.Anyone can help me by recommended book about 3-d geometry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally recommend "Analytical Geometry: 2D and 3D" by P.R.Vittal.  All concepts are explained very thoroughly. But, I feel that there are not many books exclusively devoted to that topic. Try also a Google Search. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Fourier No problem.

Answer (score 5):

John Stillwell's *The Geometry of Surfaces* is an excellent,visual and sophisticated introduction to geometry that focuses mostly in 3 dimensional space and abstract surfaces. It also has a wonderful historical bent which gives the reader a terrific insight into the developments of the subject. The one drawback for a beginner is that this isn't really a beginner's text: it requires a good working knowledge of linear algebra, basic topology and calculus and some group theory.If you don't have this background,the book might prove a bit challenging. But if you do have most of this and are willing to read up on what you're missing,I think you'll find this book exactly what you're looking for.